# How to remove <br> at the end of the line with javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

How to remove br tag at the end of the line with javascript?

```
<code>
line 1 <br>
line 2 <Br>
line 3 <br />
line 4 <br/>
</code>
```

Comment: @AliTkh: Please have a friend or coworker help you with your English. "answer not easy" is unclear, and doesn't do anything to help us help you.

Answer (score 6):

This will remove the last `br` in the *first* `code` element on your page:

```
var code = document.querySelector('code');
var brs = code.querySelectorAll('br');
var br = brs.length && brs[brs.length-1];
if (br) {
    br.parentNode.removeChild(br);
}
```

Live example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var code = document.querySelector('code');
  var brs = code.querySelectorAll('br');
  var br = brs.length && brs[brs.length-1];
  if (br) {
    br.parentNode.removeChild(br);
  }
}, 500);
```

```html
<code>
line 1 <br>
line 2 <Br>
line 3 <br />
line 4 <br/>
</code>Text after so you can see it when it goes
```

`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` both take CSS-style selectors. They're supported on all modern browsers, and also IE8. `querySelector` returns the *first* matching element in the document, if any, or `null` if none. `querySelectorAll` returns a *list* of matching elements (which could be empty, hence the check above).

The above also uses JavaScript's curiously-powerful `&&` operator, which is a cousin to its curiously-powerful `||` operator; [this post on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) explains both of them.

Of course, if you need to be more specific about which `code` element you're working on, adjust the first selector accordingly.

---

If you use jQuery, it's a bit simpler:

```
$("code").first().find("br").last().remove();
```

Live example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $("code").first().find("br").last().remove();
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code>
line 1 <br>
line 2 <Br>
line 3 <br />
line 4 <br/>
</code>Text after so you can see it when it goes
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to js; this will not remove `br` from code but `br` will no longer add a line break.

```
br {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
$("code").find("br:last").remove()
```

Using plain JS:

```
var targetElement = document.getElementsByTagName("code")[0],
lastChildElement = targetElement.lastChild;
targetElement.removeChild(lastChildElement);
```